# how can I fix document version issues / conflicts

Tags: elasticsearch

When building an index on Elasticsearch, I made a mistake when creating an index by doing an update before the previous update was finished.  The consequence is that I have version conflicts when trying to do updates across the whole index.
How can I reset the document versions and set them all back to version 0?

Comment: Is it a test index or in production? Is it a small index? You could just reindex and use an alias so you don't have to reconfigure your app. You could try the retry_on_conflict param of the update api, or use external param to set the version yourself

Comment: its a test index with 280,000 documents.  How can I use external param to set the version myself.  I was hoping to figure out how to reset all the document version back to 0.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support

Comment: We are using Elasticsearch version 5.4.1 - Reading the Versioning Support, I tried to set version type to external and version number to 1.  When trying to set version_type=external returns unrecognized parameter for version_type.    This is what I'm trying on kibana:   

POST entrad-lr-common_20180101_20171001_20180101/_update_by_query?version_type=external&version=1